# Parsing xml - getNamedItem if exists

Tags: xml, xml-parsing

I am playing with [this W3schools.com example](https://www.w3schools.com/XML/tryit.asp?filename=try_dom_getnameditem), before applying it to an xml file that I am more interested in.

The example retrieves fine the attribute "category", which is present in the [xml file](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/books.xml) for the 4 books.

But when replacing "category" by "cover" (which is present for the 4th book only) in

```
txt += x.item(i).attributes.getNamedItem("category").value + "<br>";
```

the code does not work.

Here is what I tried and that works but heavy, especially if I want to apply the condition to several attributes:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        myFunction(this);
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "https://www.w3schools.com/xml/books.xml", true);
xhttp.send();

function myFunction(xml) {
    var x, i, xmlDoc, txt;
    xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
    txt = "";
    x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('book');
    y = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('author');
    z = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('title');
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      if (x.item(i).attributes.getNamedItem("cover")) {
        txt +=  "INSERT INTO Customers (category, cover, language, author, title) VALUES ('" + 
                x.item(i).attributes.getNamedItem("category").value + ", "+
                x.item(i).attributes.getNamedItem("cover").value + ", "+
                z.item(i).attributes.getNamedItem("lang").value + ", "+
                y[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + ", "+
                z[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + ")<br>";
      } else {
        txt +=  "INSERT INTO Customers (category, cover, language, author, title) VALUES ('" + 
                x.item(i).attributes.getNamedItem("category").value + ", "+
                "NULL, "+
                z.item(i).attributes.getNamedItem("lang").value + ", "+
                y[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + ", "+
                z[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + ")<br>";
      }
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt; 
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

What is the most simple way to add a condition that returns an attribut only if present?

Thanks and regards,

Christophe

Answer (score 0):

Here what I came to:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        myFunction(this);
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "https://www.w3schools.com/xml/books.xml", true);
xhttp.send();

function myFunction(xml) {
    var x, i, xmlDoc, txt;
    xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
    txt = "";
    x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('book');
    y = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('author');
    z = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('title');
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        txt +=  "INSERT INTO Customers (category, language, author, title) VALUES (" + 
                (x.item(i).attributes.getNamedItem("category") ? "'" + x.item(i).attributes.getNamedItem("category").value + "'" : "NULL") + ", "+
                (x.item(i).attributes.getNamedItem("cover") ? "'" + x.item(i).attributes.getNamedItem("cover").value + "'" : "NULL") + ", "+
                (z.item(i).attributes.getNamedItem("lang") ? "'" + z.item(i).attributes.getNamedItem("lang").value + "'" : "NULL") + ", "+
                (y[i].childNodes[0] ? "'" + y[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "'" : "NULL") + ", "+
                (z[i].childNodes[0] ? "'" + z[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "'" : "NULL") + ")<br>"
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt; 
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Any best way to handle it?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).